# Built-in Superdrive won't read DVDs after upgrading to OS X Mavericks

Tags: dvd, osx-mavericks

After upgrading my Late-2009 iMac to Mavericks from Snow Leopard I found it will no longer mount or read DVDs inserted into the Superdrive.  CDs will read but make a horrible grinding noise on spin-up and spin-down.

Answer (score 3):

After researching this a bit and finding other people with similar issues, I came across this [Apple Knowledge Base article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2801) about trouble-shooting the slot-loading SuperDrive which advised to [reset the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) (for a non-portable this is essentially involves unplugging it from the mains for at least 15 seconds).

This seems to have done the trick and my Mac is now reading DVDs again.

Comment: Could you please at least summarize the solutions found in the articles you linked here?

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

open Terminal app

```
drutil Status
drutil info
drutil getconfig
drutil eject
```

Just try it several times and the superdrive comes alive again. This worked for my macbook pro late 2008 internal superdrive.